# Почему в консоль не правильно отображает последовательность \b?

Tags: java, syntax

Почему в консоль не правильно отображает последовательность \b?

Должна стирать предыдущий символ, в получается вот что:

```
System.out.println("привет\b"); //выводит привет и символ, который не отображается на этом сайте
```

Comment: Как запускаете вашу программу? Через `netbeans` у меня(Ubuntu) вывело вполне адекватно(Oracle JDK8)

Comment: @Chubatiy, обычным значком выполнения в IDE. Пробовал в Eclipse на windows, и в онлайн компиляторе https://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_java_online.php
Попробуйте в онлайн-компиляторе.

Comment: У меня тоже JDK 8

Comment: Судя по всему просто нет поддержки в IDE. Т.к. через компиляцию с консоли и вывод - все ок(javac test.java и потом java test)

Comment: Вот, кстати, ссылка на enSO, где это описывается https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48838329/b-behaving-weird-in-intellijs-console